# Passing a 2d vector into a function c++

Tags: c++

I have a function (assign) in a class (graph) in a header file. The objective of this function is to print a 2d vector:

```
class Graph
{
public:
    void printvec(vector< vector<double> >&PRRMap);
};
```

I call this function from a cpp file such as:

```
Graph G;
G.printvec(vector< vector<double> > &PRRmap);
```

I get the following error:

> error: expected primary-expression before `‘&’` token

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void printvec(vector< vector<double> >&PRRMap);
```

This is a declaration.  It includes *formal parameters*, each of which specifies a *type* and an optional name.

```
G.printvec(a_map);
```

This is a function call.  It includes *actual parameters*, each of which is an expression, aka value.  The type is not named during a function call.  But you do need to specify the name of the vector you want printed.

The type of the *actual parameter* expression is checked against the *formal parameter type* specified in the function declaration.  If they don't match, the compiler will look for a suitable conversion, and if it can't find one, you will get a compile error.

Since your function requires a non-const reference, most conversions will not be allowed here.  You should specify the name of a suitable vector-of-vectors object that you have prepared with the data to be printed.

Answer (score 3):

when you call the function you don't need the & operator

only the variable (a valid reference)